# Facebook Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: couldn't open file

Tags: facebook

I've got this error coming from facebook, just recently when I changed to a new server

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: couldn't open file "" thrown in /home/my/folder/here/src/base_facebook.php on line 805
```

and line 805 is (copying strings from 804) :-

```
804 if ($result === false) {
805     $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
    'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
    'error' => array(
    'message' => curl_error($ch),
    'type' => 'CurlException',
    ),
  ));
  curl_close($ch);
  throw $e;
}
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

I am not sure if the code is needed but here is pat of the code inside my file:-

```
 $album_details = array(
        'message'=> 'Which Friend is your best friend?',
        'name'=> 'Which Friend is your best friend?'
);
$create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

//Get album ID of the album you've just created
$album_uid = $create_album['id'];

//Upload a photo to album of ID...

$file='img/'.$fbid.'.jpg'; //Example image file
$data = array(array('tag_uid' => $friends, 'x' => rand() % 100, 'y' => rand() % 100 ));
$data = json_encode($data);
//, 'tags' => $data,

$photo_details = array( 'message'=> 'My Best Friend '.$friend.' . Find Out Here -> http://www.facebook.com/ <-', 'tags' => $data, 'image' => '@' . realpath($file) );
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

Everything goes fine, allowing the App, then permission page... but as soon as permission is given it ends up giving this error.

Please help...

Comment: Obviously you've specified the wrong path to the file you're trying to upload

Comment: obviously its not too obvious to the OP... ;)

Comment: Sorry...can you explain? the same path was working in the previous shared hosting. now that i've moved to vps hosting, it's breaking. Please explain? i'm quite confused

Comment: Ohh ya, forgot to mention... in the code above, i did try this path as well... $file='/home/public_html/myaccount/myfolder/img/'.$fbid.'.jpg'; 

but still it shows the error... is this what you were trying to tell me?